# How to compare header columns in different sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a dynamic way to compare header columns in multiple sheets to make sure all sheets have the same headers. Column counts may vary so I don't want to hardcode the range, instead I am trying to write something that would check for columns (UsedRange) that are not empty to do the comparison

I tried below but then I am getting an error saying

> "Conversion from type 'Object(,)' to type 'String' is not valid"

```
range1 = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Columns.Value

range2 = xlBook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Value
```

' If I could get the values then I was planning to do following

if range1 <> range2

MsgBxx .......

End if

Comment: I think you need to loop through each cell in the first row and compare each one individually with its counterpart on the other sheet. That said, this could be done with conditional formatting

Comment: Assumed that in all sheets the header is in row 1 and nothing else in row 1 but just the header, then to get the header range, maybe try something like this : `set rgHdr = sheets(1).rows(1).specialcells(xlconstants)`. So the rgHdr is the range of the header in sheet1. Then make a string variable with name "hdr" : `hdr = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rgHdr)), ",")` ---> the hdr value are the header name separated by comma. The hdr value will be as the "benchmark" to compare another value of the rgHdr in all other sheet. (continue)

Comment: Loop to the rest of the sheet, get the range of the header on each sheet as rgHdr then check if the value of this rgHdr = hdr .... `For i = 2 To Sheets.Count` ... `Set rgHdr = Sheets(i).Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlConstants)` ... `If Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rgHdr)), ",") <> hdr Then MsgBox "not same"` ... `next`